What is the _statsTracker address on some ERC-20 contracts?
I've been finding some ERC-20 contracts having a _statsTracker address, which then gets used like so:
if (_statsTracker != address(0)) {
    IStatsTracker(_statsTracker).updateTransferStats(address(this), sender, recipient, amount);
}

(example: https://etherscan.io/address/0x7556a1ed241bc4b56530c8e8e1347629c8884f23#code)
What is the canonical purpose? I've not been able to find IStatsTracker documentation anywhere.
As an aside, given IStatsTracker is an interface to an external contract, does this sort of logic expose the token to reentrancy risk (or other risks?)
As a follow up question, solidity marks this as reentrancy-benign. The documentation states:
The reentrancy is benign because it's exploitation would have the same effect as two consecutive calls.

How so? Couldn't IstatsTracker.updateTransferStats call _transfer, triggering a recursive loop?
